# Return last instance of value from column when two criteria met in row

Tags: excel, indexing, lookup

I'm having trouble getting an Excel formula that returns the last instance of a value in a column when two criteria are met in the adjacent row.

In the dummy example, I have a diary of what activities I have performed with which pets when. See image below.

[Workbook screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtaRt.png)

I'd like a formula that tells me when I last performed a particular activity with a particular pet.

For example, when did I last massage my frog? Or when did I last brush my cat?

Using `=INDEX(B:B,SUMPRODUCT(MAX((Pet=A2)*ROW(Pet))))` in B2 or `=LOOKUP(2,1/(Pet=A3),B8:B13)` B3 I can get Excel to tell me when I last did *an* activity with a particular pet.

But I'd like to know when I last did a *particular* activity with a particular pet.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Use index match for this. See https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/ for an example. I think you should sort your data from present to past however.

Comment: another way would be to use a helper column. Add a column that concatenates pet and activity into one cell, and search that column for the concatenated value. So if the pet is dog and the activity is wash, add a column that says DogWash, then search for that using vlookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula in B2 and drag down to B4:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$8:$B$13)/($A$8:$A$13=$A2),1),1)
```

Put this formula in C2, drag across to E2 and then drag down the next two rows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$8:$B$13)/(($A$8:$A$13=$A2)*($C$8:$C$13=C$1)),1),1),"-")
```

[image]

This all assumes your dates are all entered in chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your data is in the range A7:C13 including headers and pet names are listed in A2:A4, then try this...

To get service date, 
In B2

```
=MAX(INDEX(($A$8:$A$13=A2)*$B$8:$B$13,))
```

and copy down.

Then
In C2

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$8:$A$13=$A2)*($B$8:$B$13=$B2)*($C$8:$C$13=C$1),),0)),"True","")
```

and copy it across and down.

Comment: I think he wants the date that he last performed each task, not IF he performed it.

Comment: The first formula gets the last date he performed with a specific pet mentioned in the range A2:A4. :)

Comment: Ah, I see what `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$8:$A$13=$A2)*($B$8:$B$13=$B2)*($C$8:$C$13=C$1),),0)),"True","")` does: it tells me what activity I performed the last time that I serviced the pet. That's also something I'd also like to present in the sheet.

Comment: That means you didn't try the solution. Right? The first formula will give you the latest service date and the second formula will return True under service type to tell you what service you performed with a pet on that latest date. I think that is what you tried to show in the screenshot. Or maybe I couldn't understand your requirement as Jacob stated. :)

Comment: Yes, the requirement (poorly explained) was to return the date that I last performed a particular activity with a particular pet. Your solution told me what activity I performed with a pet on the last service date.